# Bootstrap - Non-Fluid Container & Row Where Background Colour is Fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Lots of answers of how nesting a container inside of a container-fluid is a bad idea. So without doing that, how do I make the background-color of my non-fluid rows take up the width of the entire screen?

You can see Bootstrap does this on thier own website with the purple but viewing the source was not helpful for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your container in a another div and apply the background color to this parent div. Please see http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/aNgvoJ

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">bootstrap row</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
  background-color:teal   
}
```

**Update**

> This is good but for alternating row background colours, one must use
>   wrap -> container -> row for each row?

If you need alternating rows each with full width background colours, it would be cleaner to use a container-fluid for your page, then use a nested container on each row: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/GZbqLV

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row one">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">one</div>
    </div> <!-- end nested container -->
  </div> <!-- end row -->  

  ...  <!-- repeat above for each row -->

  </div> <!-- end parent container -->
```

CSS

```
.one{
   background-color:pink:
}
```

Comment: This is good but for alternating row background colours, one must use wrap -> container -> row for each row. Is this just how it has to be or is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks @BFalcon Here's another variation for you: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/LNKrRG

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe

```
<style>
        .cont {
            background-color: yellow;
            height: 20em;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="cont">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
```